# .NET Azure Function App using UpsertItemAsync to upload to CosmosDB is dramatically slow, especially compared to Python's CosmosClient

Tags: python, .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a .NET Function App running on Azure, that is uploading data to CosmosDB like this:

```
foreach (var message in messages)
{
    try
    {
        await notificationsContainer.UpserItemAsync(message, message.NTID);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

The UpsertItemAsync is a wrapper:

```
public async Task<T> UpsertItemAsync(T document, string partitionKey)
{
    ItemResponse<T> response = await _container.UpsertItemAsync<T>(document, new PartitionKey(partitionKey));
    return response.Resource;
}
```

I'm doing a test with 6500 messages. It took 16 minutes to upload 640(!) messages to the database. On the same time, using Python's CosmosClient, this call

`container.create_item(message)`

times 6500, takes 131 seconds to complete.

Moreover, the Function App is running on Azure and the CosmosClient is set with direct connectivity mode:

```
 CosmosClient client = clientBuilder
    .WithConnectionModeDirect()
    .WithThrottlingRetryOptions(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, config.MaxRetryWaitTimeInMilliSeconds), config.MaxRetryCount)
    .WithBulkExecution(true)
    .Build();
```

While the python script is running on an on-prem VM.

What could be the explanation of this dramatic difference in performance? Isn't the function app incredibly slow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are enabling Bulk Mode (`.WithBulkExecution(true)`) but doing `await` on each operation.

When using Bulk Mode (reference https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/introducing-bulk-support-in-the-net-sdk/) you need to create those operations but not await individually. Something like:

```
List<Task> operations = new List<Task>();
foreach (var message in messages)
{
    operations.Add(notificationsContainer.UpserItemAsync(message, message.NTID));
}

try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(operations);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //...
}
```

Either that or disable Bulk Mode if you are going to do individual operation execution.

Comment: If I remove the bulk execution but I keep the upload code the way it is, do you think it would make a difference? (deploying and testing it would take a while)

Comment: It would definitively.